# Implement an interface method but return a more specific type

Tags: vb.net, inheritance

**Background**

I have a number of objects in a parent/children relationship like so:

- `YearNode` has a number of child `QuarterNode`
- `QuarterNode` has a number of child `TypeNode`
- `TypeNode` has a number of child `ReportsNode`

The consumer of this structure is fairly dumb: it doesn't know (or care) about the structure, it just works through the nodes and their children (spitting whatever it is given out to a treeview via a recursive for loop)

To try to implement this I created the following interface

```
Public Interface IHaveChildren
    .. bunch of properties ...
    ReadOnly Property Children As ICollection(Of IHaveChildren)
End Interface
```

Which is implemented by my above mentioned xxxNode objects. 
This works and the consumer doesn't know (or care) what type of Node it has, just that it has a Children property it should loop through.

**Requirements**

Currently the structure of Year > Qtr > Type > Report isn't enforced, as they are all `IHaveChildren` you can add a `ReportNode` to `YearNode.Children`.
To make the expected structure explicit in code (to prevent errors/make it easier to understand) I'd like to enforce the structure.
So, for example only `QuarterNode`s can be added to `YearNode`s children, but the consumers should still see them as the same.

For `YearNode` I tried this:

```
Public Overloads ReadOnly Property Children As ICollection(Of QuarterNode) Implements IHaveChildren.Children
        Get
...
```

I was hoping this would be OK as `QuarterNode` implements `IHaveChildren` but this gives me an error

> 'Children' cannot implement 'Children' because there is no matching
>   property on the interface 'IHaveChildren'.

Meaning, as I understand it, the return type `ICollection(Of QuarterNode)` cannot match `ICollection(Of IHaveChildren)` expected in the interface even though `QuarterNode` implements `IHaveChildren`.

**Other approaches**

I thought I'd try a base class, which the Node Classes would inherit and override the Children method specifying the user

```
Public MustInherit Class Node
    Public MustOverride ReadOnly Property Children As ICollection(Of Node)
End Class

Public Class NodeYear
    Inherits Node

    Public Overloads Overrides ReadOnly Property Children As ICollection(Of NodeQuarter)
        Get
            .. impl ..
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

But this gave the error

> Public Overrides Overloads ReadOnly Property Children As
>   System.Collections.Generic.ICollection(Of NodeYear)' cannot override
>   'Public MustOverride ReadOnly Property Children As
>   System.Collections.Generic.ICollection(Of Node)' because they differ
>   by their return types.

So basically the same issue as before.

I've considered creating my own implementation of ICollection that overrides the Add method to only accept a specified Type but returns a Node or IHaveChildren but that seems like overkill.
I've considered changing the local variable behind the `Children` property to the Specific type but leaving the property to Node or IHaveChildren but that doesn't seem like a smart approach (even if it worked it doesn't expose my intent from the method signature and is asking for problems)

I've also looked for SO questions and not found any that answer my question 
Is what I am trying to do possible, if so how?
or do I need to consider a different approach?

Comment: You might need two properties, one that returns the proper list as ICollection(Of QuarterNode). And the other that returns the list as interface ICollection(Of Node) which would need to do a [List.ConvertAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf(VS.90).aspx) or Enumerable.Cast. You can't easily cast a List(of T) unlike an object.

Comment: You might be able to make something work for your consumer with a generic interface with variance in the type parameter.  This wouldn't work with List(Of T) I don't believe, but it would work with IEnumerable(Of T).  Given the restrictions you want to add, I don't think your consumer should be seeing the children as a mutable collection anyway.  You might consider making NodeBase generic to allow parameterizing it on the child type.  I think putting those two together may get you most of the way to what you want.